# How to handle multi pairs for a given ID - Paired t-test

Tags: t-test

I'm comparing tattoo vs. non-tattoo in 10 subjects.  Some of these subjects have more than 1 set of tattoos. How do I handle this situation?

```
ID   Tattoo    Non-Tattoo
1      21         22
1      24         25
2      25         20
3      19         22
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ID Tattoo SR
1 yes 25
1 no 23
2 yes 21
2 no 24
3 yes 25
3 no 20
3 yes 19
3 no 18
4 yes 21
4 no 23
5 yes 26
5 no 26
5 yes 22
5 no 19

Comment: Sorry this is difficult to explain.  This data is transposed as I don't know how to attach a file.

Comment: You can see ID 3 and 5 both have 2 pairs of data.  2 for tattoo, and 2 for non-tattoo.  How do I account for this since it is the same subject.

Comment: The data example need a better layout.  I have tried an edit, but am not sute it is correct since your intent is unclear. Lines starting with 4 spaces are taken as code!  But you also need to make clear what are the measured numbers under the `tattoo` and ǹon-tattoo` columns, what do they represent. No answer will be possible until you clarify!